# Can an ant target extend multiple extension points?

Tags: apache, ant

I have two `extension points` that are slightly different but use a lot of the same `targets`, so I was wondering how to have a single `target` extend multiple `extension points`?

Comment: What is an extension point?

Comment: https://ant.apache.org/manual/targets.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `<target>` can extend multiple extension points by providing a comma-separated list to `extensionOf`:

### build.xml

```
<project name="ant-extension-points" default="t4">
    <target name="t1"/>
    <target name="t2"/>
    <extension-point name="ep1" depends="t1"/>
    <extension-point name="ep2" depends="t2"/>
    <target name="t3" extensionOf="ep1,ep2"/>
    <target name="t4" depends="ep1"/>
</project>
```

### Output

```
t1:

t3:

ep1:

t4:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Comment: `depend` is different than `extensionOf`. I am speaking about `extensionOf`. Sorry if that wasn't clear

Comment: @Dale_Plante I've edited my answer to use `extensionOf`.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure if it worked syntactically the same as `depends`